# How to bind an argument with a dual function?

Tags: pointers, vala, vapi

Consider these C functions:

```
#define INDICATE_SPECIAL_CASE -1
void prepare (long *length_or_indicator);
void execute ();
```

The prepare function is used to store a pointer to a delayed `long *` output variable.

It can be used in C like this:

```
int main (void) {
    long length_or_indicator;
    prepare (&length_or_indicator);
    execute ();
    if (length_or_indicator == INDICATE_SPECIAL_CASE) {
        // do something to handle special case
    }
    else {
        long length = lengh_or_indicator;
        // do something to handle the normal case which has a length
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve something like this in Vala:

```
int main (void) {
    long length;
    long indicator;
    prepare (out length, out indicator);
    execute ();
    if (indicator == INDICATE_SPECIAL_CASE) {
        // do something to handle special case
    }
    else {
        // do something to handle the normal case which has a length
    }
}
```

How to write the binding for `prepare ()` and `INDICATE_SPECIAL_CASE` in Vala?

Is it possible to split the variable into two?

Is it possible to avoid using pointers even though the `out` variable is written to after the call to `prepare ()` (in `execute ()`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with using `out` is that Vala is going to generate lots of temporary variables along the way, which will make the reference wrong. What you probably want to do is create a method in your VAPI that hides all this:

```
[CCode(cname = "prepare")]
private void _prepare (long *length_or_indicator);
[CCode(cname = "execute")]
private void _execute ();
[CCode(cname = "prepare_and_exec")]
public bool execute(out long length) {
  long length_or_indicator = 0;
  prepare (&length_or_indicator);
  execute ();
  if (length_or_indicator == INDICATE_SPECIAL_CASE) {
     length = 0;
     return false;
  } else {
     length = lengh_or_indicator;
     return true;
 }
}
```